# react hook not updating when referencing another hook value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So my state updates when I place an object within the setCurrentSlide function however if I directly place

```
setCurrentSlide(previousSelectedSlide);
```

then I get undefined issues. Why cant I directly place another hooks value after setting that hook value in the same useEffect hook. Am I missing something here?  I just want to replace the value of 'currentSlide' with 'previousSelectedSlide' instead of having to pass the whole object i just want to pass the value which is an object anyway.

This currently works:

```
const initialState = {
            firstSlide: true,
            secondSlide: false,
            thirdSlide: false
        }

    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(initialState);
    const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState();
    const [previousSelectedSlide, setPreviousSelectedSlide] = useState();


    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {

            setPreviousSelectedSlide(currentSlide);

            //set back to first slide
            setCurrentSlide({
                firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false
            })

            //get height of first slide
            const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
            var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
            setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 

            //set back to original state
            setCurrentSlide({firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false})
        });
             
    })
```

but I want it to work like this which it dont:

```
   const initialState = {
            firstSlide: true,
            secondSlide: false,
            thirdSlide: false
        }

    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(initialState);
    const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState();
    const [previousSelectedSlide, setPreviousSelectedSlide] = useState();


    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {

            setPreviousSelectedSlide(currentSlide);

            //set back to first slide
            setCurrentSlide({
                firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false
            })

            //get height of first slide
            const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
            var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
            setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 

            **//set back to original state
            setCurrentSlide(previousSelectedSlide)**
             
    })
```

I basically want to update the state of currentSlide to the previousSelectedSlide after I have grabbed the height of my container.

FULL CODE BLOCK:

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


const Hero = () => {
    
    const initialState = {
        firstSlide: true,
        secondSlide: false,
        thirdSlide: false
    }

    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(initialState);
    const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState();
    const [previousSelectedSlide, setPreviousSelectedSlide] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
            var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
            setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 
        })       
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {

            setPreviousSelectedSlide(currentSlide);

            //set back to first slide
            setCurrentSlide({
                firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false
            })

            //get height of first slide
            const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
            var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
            setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 

            //set back to original state
            setCurrentSlide({firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false})
            });
             
        //when broswer is resized check what the currently selected slide is quickly flip back to slide 1 grab height and store in state then go back to previous slide
    })

    const selectSlide = (e) => {
        switch(e.target.value) {
            case "first":
                setCurrentSlide({
                    firstSlide: true, 
                    secondSlide: false, 
                    thirdSlide: false
                });
            break;
            case "second":
                setCurrentSlide({
                    firstSlide: false, 
                    secondSlide: true, 
                    thirdSlide: false
                });
            break;
            case "third":
                setCurrentSlide({
                    firstSlide: false, 
                    secondSlide: false, 
                    thirdSlide: true
                });
            break;
        }
    }

    return (
        
        <div className="hero-main-container">
            {currentSlide.firstSlide &&
            <div className="hero-first-slide">
                <div className="embed-container">
                    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/483154931?autoplay=1&loop=1&background=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>}    
            {currentSlide.secondSlide &&
            <div className="hero-second-slide" style={{height: containerHeight}}>
                <div className="">
                    <img src="" />
                </div>
                <div className="second-slide-right">
                </div>
            </div>}
            {currentSlide.thirdSlide &&
            <div className="hero-third-slide" style={{height: containerHeight}}>
                3
            </div>}
            <div className="numbered-pagination-container">
                <div className="numbered-pagination">
                    <button className={currentSlide.firstSlide ? 'active-button' : ''} onClick={(e) => selectSlide(e)} value="first" type="button">1</button>
                    <button className={currentSlide.secondSlide ? 'active-button' : ''} onClick={(e) => selectSlide(e)} value="second" type="button">2</button>
                    <button className={currentSlide.thirdSlide ? 'active-button' : ''} onClick={(e) => selectSlide(e)} value="third" type="button">3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Kind of hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you be more specific on what you expect to solve.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I basically want to replace the currentSlide with the previousSelectedSlide but it wont work.

Comment: setState calls are asynchronous as React batches them up, figures the result and efficiently makes the change. By the time setCurrentSlide(previousSelectedSlide) runs, it still points to undefined. Pass a function that sets previousSlide to setPreviousSelectedSlide instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to have a state for previousSelectedSlide? Is there any purpose for that? However, you can access the previous state of currentSlide by passing a callback into the updated function like this:

```
  setCurrentSlide(previousSelectedSlide => { 

            // You can do things with previouseSelectedSlide here

            //get height of first slide
            const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
            var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
            setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 

            return {
                firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false
             }
    )
```

Comment: Still a little confused. I want to re initialise the previous state object after I have gathered the height of my container. So they are returned to the slide they was previously viewing. So i want to store the current slide they are viewing by grabbing the currentSlide value and storing it in previousSelectedSlide so i then have a reference to this after i have grabbed my firstslides height. I can then update the state again to give them the previous state. Therefore if they was on slide 2 they would stay on slide 2 etc. Hard to explain

Comment: updated question so you can see the full block of code and what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it using refs

```
const initialState = {
    firstSlide: true,
    secondSlide: false,
    thirdSlide: false
}

const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(initialState);
const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState();
// const [previousSelectedSlide, setPreviousSelectedSlide] = useState();
const prevSlideRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
        var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
        setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 
    })       
})

useEffect(() => {
    let doit;

    window.onresize = () => {
        clearTimeout(doit);
        doit = setTimeout(function() {
            prevSlideRef.current = currentSlide;

            const prevSlide = prevSlideRef.current;
            //set back to first slide
            setCurrentSlide({
                firstSlide: true, 
                secondSlide: false, 
                thirdSlide: false
            })

            //get height of first slide
            const firstSlide = document.querySelector('.hero-first-slide');
            var height = firstSlide.scrollHeight;  
            setContainerHeight(height + 'px'); 

            //set back to original state
            setCurrentSlide(prevSlide);
        }, 100);
    }
                     
})
```